# Modifying qmake file to build to multiple targets for use with '#IFDEF macro'

Tags: c++, qt

I want to modify my Qt project's qmake file in such a way that it builds two versions of my program: one where `SOME_FLAG` is defined and one where it is not. My code will behave differently depending on the result of `#ifdef SOME_FLAG`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What platform are you on and what is your criteria for setting the define?  @Paolo has the answer, the only question left is what conditional do you want to use?  There are a number of approaches.

Comment: I'm in a Linux environment. I'm building two binaries for the same platform, but with some minor differences in code. I'd like to be able to build both targets by executing the default `qmake` command without any parameters.

Comment: You can use environment variables to select the options you want.  The project file can then choose which defines to use on that basis.  Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. When I compile my project in Qt Creator, I want qmake to build to both `./withSomeFlag` (program is compiled with the inclusion of `#ifdef SOME_FLAG` sections) as well as `./withoutSomeFlag` (program is compiled with the inclusion of `#ifndef SOME_FLAG` sections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, qmake only allows one TARGET, with one exception.  That being, if you want to build a debug version and a release version, it is possible to build both with the same project file.  This way, you can also specify the DEFINES for each build separately.  Keep in mind that you can use the strip command to remove debugging after the fact, and maybe this will be usable for your circumstances.  The Qt4 HTML docs (look to see if they are installed on your system) describes the debug_and_release mode in qmake-common-projects.html .

Now that said, you are allowed multiple project files.  Create one project for each executable, with the desired DEFINES for each project.  Use the qmake -o flag to issue separate Makefiles for each target and one Makefile to bind them.  Can't help you with QtCreator, because I do not use it, but this works on the command line.  A sample Makefile that illustrates this scheme would look something like this:

```
all: Makefile_A Makefile_B
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile_A
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile_B

Makefile_A: withSomeFlag.pro
        qmake -o $@ $<

Makefile_B: withoutSomeFlag.pro
        qmake -o $@ $<
```

This is just a quick file that does the job, somebody better at Makefiles might make it more generic.  **NOTE:** the Makefile indentations are *single TAB characters*, not 8 spaces.

Also note that, by default, the executable name is the same as the basename of the project file.  Hope that this gets you going in some capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
DEFINES += "SOME_FLAG"
```

in your `.pro` file, presumably within a conditional.